# При сохранении куки в php не могу прочитать и получить ее значение в javascript - почему?

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, cookie

Есть сайт на `wordpress`, где в `php` части сохраняю переменную в `cookie`

```
$sum = 5;
setcookie("sum", $sum, time()+2592000000);
```

А в `js` части пытаюсь ее извлечь:

```
  function getCookie(name) {
     var matches = document.cookie.match(new RegExp("(?:^|; )" + name.replace(/([\.$?*|{}\(\)\[\]\\\/\+^])/g, '\\$1') + "=([^;]*)"));
     return matches ? decodeURIComponent(matches[1]) : false;
  }
var sum = 0;
var hostname = document.location.hostname.split('.');
var domain = hostname[hostname.length - 2] + '.' + hostname[hostname.length - 1];
if (!getCookie('sum')) {
         document.cookie = "sum=" + sum + "; path=/; domain=" + domain + "; expires=" + dateCookie.toUTCString();
} else {
   sum = parseInt(getCookie('sum'));
}
alert("Сумма: ", sum);
```

Но, по какой-то причине в хранилище добавляется повторная куки с одинаковыми именами, т.е. в `js` не идентифицируется уже хранящееся куки с таким же названием. Как `js` научить узнавать куки по имени?

Comment: А где, собственно функция `getCookie`?

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko дополнил

Comment: А почему в php у вас `$sum = 5`, а записываете вы `$value`?